# ESXi 5 host-only test environment

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm setting up a test environment. I have ESXi installed with a few operating systems. I'm trying to have these few operating systems in host-only mode they don't don't talk outside the host but I cannot find this setting anywhere in my vSphere Client (also v5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be accomplished by setting up a virtual switch (vSwitch) that does not have any physical uplinks to the rest of your network. Set the guest VMs to use this newly-created switch as their default. That will result in the desired isolation.

Answer (score 4):

If by "talk" you mean the network access is only within the host itself.  Simply setup a vSwitch that does not have physical NIC attached to it.  Then on the virtual machine(s) set the NIC to be connected to that newly created vSwitch network label.